# How to make a bottom slide in Canvas showing content with CSS, jquery and Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, canvas

i have this idea, having something like a slide in menu or html or even a canvas where the user can see a dynamic filled data table.

The target is to get the "site" (**bottom sheet**) slide in from the bottom by click on a small visible button. The site should slide 70% to the top site. Preferable using Bootstrap 4 components, JS, jquery and CSS.

I have absolutely no clue how to start, i would assume something similar to an hidden sidebar menu?

Kindly want your feedback on this.

Thanks,

Comment: split it up into small parts an do the stuff you know. this question is currently way too broad to answer. if you have a problem with a part of your code you can ask it again.

Comment: If you set a <div> to `position: fixed; top: 100vh;` it will be just outside the bottom. Now set it to `top: 30vh` and it will move into view.

Comment: @ChrisG I could do an button with onClick action to change the position from 100vh to top 30 vh, this would let me handle the position on demand right?

Comment: @ChrisG isn't it about asking? I am asking for feedback.

Comment: @ChrisG I am personally OK with questions asking just to point at some direction. There was one time a (non-beginner) coder asked a quite broad question here, I just elaborated what does he have in mind and laid out few solutions to which he replied, that it helped him to realize a direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```js
$("input[type=submit]").click(function() {
  $(".bottomStuff").toggleClass("active");
});
setInterval("console.log('update bottom content every 5 seconds, probably via ajax')",5000);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{
   max-height:50px!important;
}

.bottomStuff {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: -70%;
  height: 70%;
  width: 100%;
  background:#ccc;
  text-align:center;
  transition: bottom .5s;
}

.bottomStuff.active {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
}

.bottomStuff div {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="submit" value="Trigger me!" />
<div class="bottomStuff">
  <div>0</div>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what i was thinking about. I made it a bit bigger so it looks like a real bottom sheet. Thumbs up.. :)

Comment: @Chris Your suggested edit makes the generic answer and the rendered result less comprehensible in my opinion. If it's to help anyone in the future, i would leave it simple as it is if you don't mind. (Not meant in offensive way)

Comment: sure. No problem, my intention was to make it a bit more visual, but you are right, the container and the extra BS staff makes it difficult to understand. Kindly disregard my changes. :)

Comment: To be honest i am not sure if rejecting changes does negatively effect reputation, so i have just changed it a bit and "improved" your edit. Happy coding!